# How Do I test X11Forwarding is disabled or not

Tags: linux, ssh

I have disabled the `X11Forwarding` on my Dell server's sshd_config file by setting the `X11Forwarding` parameter:

`X11Forwarding no`

But I am not sure on how to test it.  I tried `echo "$DISPLAY"` but it shows me nothing.

Can anyone let me know how to test that `X11Forwarding` is disabled now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether X11 forwarding was negotiated by adding `-v` in your ssh command:

Requested, Enabled:

```
…
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ws1 ([192.168.0.7]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
Last login: Tue Dec  3 17:25:37 2013 from challenger.brazzers.com
michael@ws1:~>
```

Requested, Denied:

```
…
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ws1 ([192.168.0.7]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Last login: Wed Dec  4 11:56:17 2013 from challenger.brazzers.com
michael@ws1:~>
```

Not requested:

```
…
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to ws1 ([192.168.0.7]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_CA.UTF-8
Last login: Wed Dec  4 11:58:45 2013 from challenger.brazzers.com
michael@ws1:~>
```

Comment: Thanks MikeyB for your response .My command to check the same is like this ssh -v user_name@Ip_address and it should show "X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0" if x11 forwarding is disable right?

Comment: Exactly.  But only if it was requested in the first place (add `-X`).

Answer (score 1):

You actually answered your own question - $DISPLAY would be set if you connected to the server with ssh -X (enabling the X11 forwarding), and you have it properly enabled.

You can also confirm by launching an application that would make use of X (xclock is an easy option - it has a small footprint to install) after connecting with -X. If forwarding is properly disabled, it will throw an error similar to:

```
[root@redacted ~]# xclock
Error: Can't open display:
```

Hope this helps - not sure of a better way to check this.

Comment: Thanks nerve ,$DISPLAY or xclock I have to run from host machine,right??

Comment: You'd SSH into the remote machine (that has X11 forwarding disabled) and check both of those things, yes.